# Avoiding \ensuremath when incorporating backslash \ in better-bibtex export from zotero

Tags: bibtex, zotero, better-bibtex

I am writing a paper that needs various elements of the references to be enclosed in `\pkg{blahblah}`. When I try to include this directly in zotero, the zotero regular `bibtex` export outputs exactly what I need. However, I am using `better-bibtex` to ensure adequate key handling, and `better-bibtex` wraps this segment in a `\ensuremath{`, which breaks the handling of these sections in my document. I tried `{\pkg{blahblah}}`  but this didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<pre>...</pre>` in Zotero passes the contents as raw LaTeX:

```
<pre>\pkg{blahblah}</pre>
```